# D3 Text on Bar Graphs with Negative Values

Tags: javascript, text, d3.js

Managed to fix the text issue but there is something that REALLY confuses me.

```
    //Version A
        svg.selectAll()
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("text")
        .text(function(d) {return d.State;})
        .attr("x", x(00))
        .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d.State);});
//Version B
        svg.selectAll("text")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("text")
            .text(function(d) {return d.State;})
            .attr("x", x(00))
            .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d.State);});
```

Version A does what I want, which is the print all 50 states on each bar. However, Version B, which felt correct, somehow SKIPS the states before Florida. I checked within the DOM and they indeed are skipped. This isn't something that requires immediate attention but something I'm totally confused about.

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/2/)?

Comment: I have. But when I attempted to append "text" to my svg element, it didn't show up anywhere.

Comment: You've probably appended the text to the rects. You need to append them to the top-level SVG or `g`.

Comment: Not necessarily. I changed the code above to show what I think is the right approach, which is to append text to the overall svg. Unless I should append "g" first before "text"?

Comment: Could you post a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: Here is the issue I'm having now. Updated the code with what seems to be an approach. However, this code, when applied to the provided picture, only prints out the first bar's state, which is Alabama, and stops printing afterwards. Seems to be nothing wrong with the code error wise but function wise it is not what I want. I want it for all 50 states, each name being shown on each bar.

Comment: NVM I figured out the text issue, but there is something that REALLY CONFUSES ME and I don't know why. I've cleared out everything else but this bit. Check the problem.

Comment: You have `text` elements in your SVG already which are being selected and matched. Try something like `d3.selectAll("text.label")` and then give that class to the labels you add.